# Maximum level of nesting HTML elements

Tags: html

Lets say I have a HTML page like

```
<div>
  <div>
     <div>
      .....
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Like above, to what extent we can nest the html elements?

Or in other words, if we make a tree out of the HTML containers of the page, what is the limit on the height of the tree?

Comment: Until the browser's memory fills up.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that how deep can a tree get depends pretty much of how much memory has your computer.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343067/how-many-nested-tags-in-html-can-you-have-before-it-crashes-a-browser

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a limit to how deep an HTML document or CSS tree can be?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429031/is-there-a-limit-to-how-deep-an-html-document-or-css-tree-can-be)

Comment: what @ChrisHardie said, or until you get bored..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't a maximum value in any specifications that I can find. Why not test it out? As noted in the comments the upper limit is probably the amount of memory your browser can consume.

**[Here's a test jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2mP2/4/)**.

It creates `1` nested div every `10ms`. My browser starts to slow around the `1500` mark.

Comment: I like your test. I successfully reached 10000 divs, no problem there.

Comment: @Oltarus I'm using a middle-of-the-range laptop with 8GB RAM, i7 3.10GHz CPU. My browser starts to get sluggish at about 1500, and rate of divs/sec decreases noticeably before 2000.

Comment: I have a 15.4 GB RAM, i7 3.50 GHz x8 CPU, still no lag after 10000, I'm guessing your initial assumption of no limit is correct. I don't have time to test it through, though. I don't have `infinity ms` to spend on that. There may be a limit at some MAX_VALUE, but so high that it doesn't matter. Frankly, does anyone uses more that 100 imbricated divs?

Comment: for me, chrome crashes in around 2000 and firefox crashes in around 8000,
also note that i have 64gb of ram and a i7 4.60GHz x12 cpu, so it's not a resource problem